# How to do partial carriage return

Tags: python

I want to replace the cmd output of my Python script, without overwriting the first three characters of the line. Here is what I mean:

How I want it:

```
>>>ID1 downloading
>>>ID1 converting
>>>ID1 finished
```

With `/r`:

```
>>>ID0 downloading
>>>converting
>>>finished
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't fundamentally a Python question; it's a standard output question.

The standard output doesn't work that way. The simplest thing is to just rewrite "ID1".

Otherwise you will need to move to something more advanced: either console-specific formatting commands (like ANSI), or a library like `curses`.

Comment: I assume by "rewrite" you mean "write again". Agreed, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But this may not work in IDLE.

```
from time import sleep
from sys import stdout
stdout.write("\r%s" % "ID1 downloading")
stdout.flush()
sleep(1)
stdout.write("\r%s" % "ID1 converting ")
stdout.flush()
sleep(1)
stdout.write("\r%s" % "ID1 done       ")
stdout.write("\r  \r\n") # clean up
```